# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined vuejs, vuex , Webpack SSR

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuex, server-side-rendering

getting error when i define production configuration in webpack

Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

code like
      console.log(process)

```
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"

 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   module.exports.devtool = "#source-map";
   // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     "process.env": {
       NODE_ENV: '"production"'
    }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me when i add in Webpack.base.js -- libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'-- like change from

(Webpack.js or Webpack.base.js or Webpack.config.js)

```
 output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
   publicPath: "/dist/",
   filename: "build.js"
  }
```

to

```
output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
   publicPath: "/dist/",
   filename: "build.js",
   libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'  
  },
```

libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
         //this option allows users to insert comments within the export wrapper. To insert the same comment for each libraryTarget type, set auxiliaryComment to a string:
 [read more](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/)